# Why am I receiving a runtime error when I have a file created?

Tags: java, runtime-error, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

Below is a code I created in a text editor called GNU/Emacs for a college class.  This is a beginner's level Java class.  Here is my problem.  I'm not experiencing any compilation errors with this code.  However, when I try to execute it, I'm getting the following error: 
[Runtime Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/498aG.png)

I saved the actual txt file in the same folder the class and java file is in.  I'm not sure why I still cannot compile.  Please advise. Should I be putting it in a different folder?

```
import java.util*; import java.io.*; import java.lang.object;

public class bowling7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        Scanner bowling = new Scanner(new FileReader("bowling7.txt"));
        String[] TeamBlue = new String[10];
        String[] TeamWhite = new String[10];
        int[] TBScore = new int[10];
        int[] TWScore = new int[10];
        int TotalBlue = 0;
        int TotalWhite = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        String intro = "This program displays the team, members, and score of the winning team."
            System.out.println(intro);

        while(bowling.hasNextLine() == true){

            for(int counter = 0; counter < 11; ++counter){
                if (bowling.findInLine("Blue").equals("Blue")){

                    TeamBlue [counter] = bowling.next();
                    TBScore [counter] = bowling.nextInt();
                    TotalWhite = TotalWhite + TBScore [counter];

                }
                else {

                    TeamWhite [counter] = bowling.next();
                    TWScore [counter] = bowling.nextInt();
                    TotalBlue = TotalBlue + TWScore [counter];
                }
            }
        }

        if (TotalBlue>TotalWhite) {
            System.out.println("Team Blue");
            System.out.println(TeamBlue);
            System.out.println(TotalBlue);
            else {
                System.out.println("Team White");
                System.out.println(TeamWhite);
                System.out.println(TotalWhite);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the formatting

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace as code-formatted text in your question. Don't use screenshots.

Comment: First, please edit your question to post the error in text. Second, the program can't find your file according to the error. Where is bowling7.txt?

Comment: Apologies.  I fixed the error.  I input the wrong file name

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear: 'bowling7.txt' isn't there.

Java resolves relative paths to the 'current working directory' of the java process, which is normally the same as the working directory you are in when you execute the 'java' command to run this class.

You can check what it is with the following line of code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

NB: Separate notice; `import java.lang.object;` is a compile-time error, as `Object` is written with a leading capital; like all classes in the `java.lang` package, it is imported by default; you should just remove that part entirely.

NB2: Java convention is that ClassNamesAreLikeSo, fieldsAndVariablesAndParametersLikeSo; as they say, when in rome...

Comment: Alright, so I realized I put the wrong file name in the code hehe.  So that solved that error.  But another error has occurred: an inputmismatch exception.  Thoughts?

Comment: Stop using findInLine; try .next(). You should ask a new SO question or this is going to get very muddled.